# To see this vs to see

Tags: grammar

I was wondering about the following two examples if both can be used:

The preceding example sentence:

> In formula XYZ the noncentrality parameter indicates the degree of model misspecification.

The explanation why the parameter is indicative of the above:

> To see this, .....

or

> To see, ....

In both cases I want to link the explanation to the previous sentence by using `to see` or `to see this`. The latter is what I thought was right, but my 'feeling' might be biased because we use it like that in my native language (Dutch). That is, we would never leave 'this' out in the sentence.

Looking forward to hearing what's grammatically right or if both are, what would usually be the preferred way.

**EDIT** I somewhere came across 'to see, ...' and am since in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also agree that you should include the pronoun "this." You can say "To see **this**..." or "To see why **this** is true..." Having the the pronoun in position links your explanation to the previous sentence, and provides the subject for the first sentence of your explanation. Just my humble opinion.